# confused about putchar result in C

Tags: c, putchar

I have a question regarding the putchar function in C. While I was studying, I stumbled upon the following statement:
`printf("%c\n",putchar('A'+1)+2);`
When I compile and execute the programme, the result is BD. I undestand that when we type `putchar('A' + 1)` the result will be B, but how did we get the D? Doesn't this function return one character at a time?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `putchar` returns the character written ('B') and then you add 2 to this ('D') and pass it as an argument to `printf`.

Comment: [This `putchar` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar) should be very helpful.

Comment: What did you expect? What in the man-page did you not understand? What du see in the debugger? "Doesn't this function return one character at a time?" - how many characters are `'D'`?

Comment: "Doesn't this function (`putchar()`) return one character at a time?" --> yes, it printed 1 character: `B`.  Note that code printed 3 `char` in all:  `'B'`, `'D'`, `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

`putchar` is doing two things:

1. Writing the character 'B' to `stdout`
2. Returning the char 'B' as the result of the function call.

Since 'B' is returned by `putchar`, it then has 2 added to it making it 'D'. This is passed as a parameter to `printf` which then writes "D\n" to `stdout`.